# How to display timer for cron job

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cron

I am currently working on a site that sumbit data from one table in the database to another table in the same database every 12th hour. I would like to display a timer that shows when the specific cron job is scheduled to run.

Maybe if this could be done in jquery to set up an automatic timer?

I hope someone know what to do to display this.

Comment: get the time of your the server.  deduct the time to the scheduled task of your cron.  process the remaining time on javascript/jquery

Comment: You probably know what your cron is running for example at 00:00 and 12:00, so display time left until this time :)

Comment: Is it possible to see the exact time scheduled for a specific cron job in cpanel?

Comment: This is for a strategi game where it is very important that the user is able to do a specific action in the same moment as the cron job has been qued.

Answer (score 0):

to do so You can do it by 2 ways as i know and there is the easy way and the hard way

**1. the easy way**

set the timer on your cron job and you can set same timer on a jquery clock there is a lot of them if you are using Chrome you can find them here on Chrome Store
[Count Down Timer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/countdown%20timer)

**2.The Hard way**

is to access the Cpanel API and write your own Code to get the time

[Cpanel API](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiCron)

**That's what i came up with**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look more into CPanel API for sure !